# Android Gradle dexcount-gradle-plugin

Tags: plugins, android-gradle-plugin, dex

I read the documentation but I could not make it. I am using Android Studio 2.0 Stable version.

This is my project level build.gradle file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is app module level build.gradle file :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.4.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

dexcount {
    format = "list"
    includeClasses = false
    includeFieldCount = true
    includeTotalMethodCount = false
    orderByMethodCount = false
    verbose = false
    maxTreeDepth = Integer.MAX_VALUE
    teamCityIntegration = false
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my_package_name"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.3.0'
    googlePlayServicesVersion = '8.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:percent:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // eventbus
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

    // rate me dialog
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:0.5.6'

    // apache commons-io
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.0.1'
}
```

this is giving error everytime :

```
Error:(11, 0) Dexcount plugin requires the Android plugin to be configured
```

what is the solution of this error ?

Comment: Have you tried applying the android plugin? :)

Comment: android plugin is already applied but I changed the line of "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'" with "apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'" and it's worked. thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: Please do not edit a solution into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below.

Comment: @Matt okay I did, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION**

I shifted the line of

"apply plugin: 'com.android.application'"

with

"apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'"

and it's worked

Comment: Move the application plugin above the dexcount plugin as suggested by OmerKarakose

Answer (score 0):

It is documented in [Dex count's GitHub repo](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin#usage):

```
// make sure this line comes *after* you apply the Android plugin
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```

So as you said, just make sure that the Android plugin is before the Dex count plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```